# Не работает пагинация на запросе с queryBuilder

Tags: doctrine, querybuilder

Мне нужно достать статьи и количество комментариев к статье. Делаю так:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select([
                'a.id',
                'a.name',
                'a.text',
                'COUNT(c.article) as comment_count'
            ])
            ->from(Article::class, 'a')
            ->leftJoin(Comment::class, 'c', Join::WITH, "c.article = a.id")
            ->groupBy('c.article, a.id')
            ->getQuery;
```

Так все работает, но мне нужно сюда еще добавить пагинацию. Пробую так:

```
$paginator = new Paginator(new DoctrinePaginator(new ORMPaginator($query)));
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page)->setItemCountPerPage($perPage);
```

После того как начинаю бегать циклом foreach по $paginator то вываливается ошибка:

```
Error producing an iterator
```

Comment: Я заглянул к вам в профиль и обнаружил, что вы приняли только один ответ на 58 заданных вами вопросов. Вам действительно не подошли остальные или вы игнорируете правила ресурса?

Comment: На большинство вопросов я так и не получаю ответов, на многие отвечаю себе сам. Но, скорее всего, да, я просто не ставлю "лайки". Готов исправить ситуацию)